# Get consistent Key error: \n

Tags: python, keyerror

When trying to run a script containing the following code for generating text block:

```
from textwrap import dedent

text = dedent("""\
   yada yada '1' ('2','3',4') 
   ('{0}', Null, '{1}',
   '{
      "Hello":"world",
    }', '1', '{2}');""").format("yada1","yada2","yada3")
```

I get consistent error `KeyError '\n "Hello"`
and trace back pointing at the line of the `.format()`.

When I remove the `format` everything is ok, but I need it to enter parameters dynamically.
(Originally its reside inside a loop)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to double the `{` and `}` characters that are not placeholders:

```
text = dedent("""\
   yada yada '1' ('2','3',4') 
   ('{0}', Null, '{1}',
   '{{
      "Hello":"world",
    }}', '1', '{2}');""").format("yada1","yada2","yada3")
```

otherwise Python sees a `{\n  "Hello":"world",\n}` placeholder, where the part up to the `:` is the placeholder name.

From the [*Format String Syntax* documenattion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal text, which is copied unchanged to the output. **If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`.**

(emphasis mine).