# using print to print css, while using format mehtod

Tags: python

I am writing HTML to a file, suddenly I came accross this problem here:

```
theBody = "<h1>example</h1>"
with open("/home/mathew/Desktop/finalText.html", "w") as output:
        print("""<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        body{
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 2em;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        {}
        </body>
        </html>
        """.format(theBody), file=output)
```

The error I am facing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/API/index.py", line 14, in <module>
    print("""<!doctype html>
KeyError: '\n    background'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use double brace for everything that `format` should ignore, e.g.

```
>>> print('{{ignore}}{}'.format('foo'))
{ignore}foo
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224197/get-consistent-key-error-n), you have to double the `{` and `}` characters that are not placeholders. In your case:

```
body{{
 background: #000;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 }}
```